# Images missing from print view - K2

Tags: joomla-3.x, css

I'm not sure whether this is Joomla related or general however, When clicking print on the following page there should be images at the bottom of the page where it says sponsors, no matter what I do i cannot seem to get the images to display. I've checked and it isn't the 'Background and images' setting in the print dialogue.

Link to page for printing

I have a print.css file which has the following css in it:

```
    @media print{
       .prog a{display:none;}
       .prog img, .news {display:none;}
       .prog .span8 .row-fluid {margin-bottom:0;}
        .accordion-inner {display:none;}
        #footer ul {display:none;}
}
```

I just cannot get the images to appear - can any one advise what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance
D

Edit:Link Removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class called `prog` on your body tag.

This means that `.prog a{display:none;}` and `.prog img {display:none;}` will hide any link and any image on the page.

If you just want to apply these styles to your left column, then replace `.prog` with `#main`

It seems a CSS issue rather than a Joomla one.

Generally, learning to use your console's CSS inspector is the best way to find out why things are or are not appearing.  If you temporarily remove the    `@media print{` (and closing brace) from the print stylesheet then you can see in browser how it will look to a printer.  You can also do this via various in-browser means depending on which browser you are using - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452713/suggestions-for-debugging-print-stylesheets